# Not able to access springboot application running inside a container on MacOs

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a springboot application running inside a container on macOS Catalina. Logs show that the application is up and running inside the container however I cannot reach it from browser.
I have tried accessing it using :

> ```
> localhost:8081/ 
> 0.0.0.0:8081/    and 
> 127.0.0.1/8081/
> ```

But nothing helped. I have also added `server.address=0.0.0.0` to my application.properties file but that didn't help either.

This is how I run my container:

`docker run --name spring_boot_docker -it  --link mysql-dev-server:db -p 8081:8081 demo_docker_kubernetes`

Logs show application is running fine:

```
 2020-04-12 00:21:40.149  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-12 00:21:40.632  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with 
context path ''
2020-04-12 00:21:40.637  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.microservice.DemoApplication         
: Started DemoApplication in 8.519 seconds (JVM running for 9.391)
2020-04-12 00:21:52.209  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       
: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-12 00:21:52.210  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        
: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-12 00:21:52.227  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        
: Completed initialization in 17 ms
```

When I do `docker container ls` I get below output under "ports":
`0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp` if that helps anyway?

I have referred almost all other posts that suggest to include `server.address=0.0.0.0` in application.properties but as I mentioned that has not helped me.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: can you ping google.com from the container or any docker container?

Comment: @Richard - Yes, I am able to ping.

Comment: is 8081 exposed in your dockerfIle? like `EXPOSE 8081`

Comment: @SMaZ - Yes, it is exposed.

Comment: publish container IP with localhost IP thus ----> 
    `docker run --name spring_boot_docker -it  --link mysql-dev-server:db -p 
    127.0.0.1:8081:8081/tcp`

Comment: @malverndongeni - it didn't help either.

Comment: map docker container port 8080 to port 8081 ----> docker run --name spring_boot_docker -it --link mysql-dev-server:db -p 127.0.0.1:8081:8080/tcp

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the --link in your docker run to access it.

--link is a deprecated Docker feature, so there may be a docker network being created between those two containers. Rendering your -p 8081:8081 useless.

Comment: I have removed --link and now I am running both the containers in the same network that I have created. But I am still not able to access the application. I have confirmed that both the containers are on the network by inspecting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application Production mode then by default it uses HTTPS and you might be using localhost(HTTP) to access the host.

Comment: Hey sorry, but what do you mean by production mode? I noticed one thing that the application is at least being hit using HTTPS. I got 'Error parsing HTTP request header' in the logs.

Comment: I have faced same issue in Docker container at MacOS. You are able to access application in HTTPS because it is in Production Mode (means normal application start). But when i tried to have K8's orchestration along with container pods i didn't face any issues. Requesting you to have look on this link too. [link] https://medium.com/@balint_sera/access-macos-host-from-a-docker-container-e0c2d0273d7f